# Proof of Sum of Trinomial Coeffs = $3^n$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

I'm trying to prove that the sum of trinomial coeffs $\sum_{l+k+m=n}^n \binom{n}{l,k,m} = 3^n$.
I tried by induction and got the step as follows:

$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{l+k+m=n+1}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{l,k,m}
 &= \sum_{l+k+m=n+1}^{n+1}\left[\binom{n}{l-1,k,m}
                               +\binom{n}{l,k-1,m}
                               +\binom{n+1}{l,k,m-1} \right]\\
 &= 3^n+3^n+\sum_{l+k+m=n+1}^{n+1} \binom{n}{l,k,m-1}(n+1) \\
 &= 3^n+3^n+3^n(n+1)
\end{split}
$$
Clearly this doesn't add up. I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction or if the last step with the trinomial is even correct.

In addition, is it correct to even say $\sum_{l+k+m=n+1}^{n+1}\binom{n}{l-1,k,m}=3^n$, I thought so because it is equivalent to choosing three numbers whose sum is n.
**Edit:** My problem with the last equation is that $0 \leq k,l,m \leq n+1$, which means that $k-1, l-1, m-1$ may be equal to $-1$, which -I assume- will disturb the sum.

Comment: Isn't it just $(1+1+1)^n = 3^n$? As in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_expansion

Comment: It is, but I'm trying to prove it without that equation, based on the sum of rows in pascal's triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $\binom{n+1}{l,k,m-1}$ should instead be $\binom{n}{l,k,m-1}$.  After you correct that, you end up with $3^n+3^n+3^n=3^{n+1}$, as desired.

---

The induction hypothesis is $$\sum_{\substack{k \ge 0, l \ge 0, m \ge 0:\\ k+l+m=n}} \binom{n}{k,l,m} = 3^n$$
Now
\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{k \ge 0, l \ge 0, m \ge 0:\\ k+l+m=n+1}} \binom{n+1}{k,l,m} 
&=
\sum_{\substack{k \ge 0, l \ge 0, m \ge 0:\\ k+l+m=n+1}} \left(
\binom{n}{k-1,l,m} 
+\binom{n}{k,l-1,m} 
+\binom{n}{k,l,m-1} 
\right)
\\
&= 
3 \sum_{\substack{k \ge 0, l \ge 0, m \ge 0:\\ k+l+m=n+1}} \binom{n}{k-1,l,m} \\
&= 
3 \sum_{\substack{k \ge 1, l \ge 0, m \ge 0:\\ k+l+m=n+1}} \binom{n}{k-1,l,m} \\
&= 
3 \sum_{\substack{k-1 \ge 0, l \ge 0, m \ge 0:\\ k-1+l+m=n}} \binom{n}{k-1,l,m} \\
&= 
3 \sum_{\substack{j \ge 0, l \ge 0, m \ge 0:\\ j+l+m=n}} \binom{n}{j,l,m} \\
&= 
3 \cdot 3^n \\
&= 
3^{n+1}
\end{align}

Comment: I see, Thank you.
Regarding my last note however, what about the possibility that $k-1, l-1, m-1 = -1$, since $0 \leq k,l,m \leq n+1$?

Comment: @AhmadMassalha I added more details to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The standard proof for binomial coefficients is to consider $(1 + 1)^n$.

First, see the start of [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_expansion).

Then, simply consider $(1 + 1 + 1)^n.$